# How to match special characters and replace the corresponding string?

Tags: regex

Learning regular expressions, Im trying to replace some words which have `@` and `.` inside like an email adress in my example. I have tried several combinations but none has worked out.

```
public class extraction {

        public static void main(String args[]){

            String outText="";
            String inText="Hello my email as me@google.com and not me@goolgle; but you can also use  me@custom-mail.com";
            outText = inText.replaceAll("/[@/\\.]", "NOTAVAILABLE");
            System.out.println(outText);

            // Expected: Hello my email as NOTAVAILABLE and not me@goolgle; but you can also use  NOTAVAILABLE

        }

    }
```

Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for search:

```
[^\s@]+@[^\s.]+\.\S+
```

and replace by `"NOTAVAILABLE"` string.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZhftMc/1)

**Code:**

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\s@]+@[^\\s.]+\\.\\S+", "NOTAVAILABLE");
```

**Explanation:**

- `[^\s@]+`: Match 1+ characters that are not whitespace and not a `@`
- `@`: Match `@`
- `[^\s.]+`: Match 1+ characters that are not whitespace and not a dot
- `\.`: Match a literal dot
- `\S+`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/V9qThA) (courtesy @ctwheels)